# Examples of well-known software products which have gone through major rewrites?

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to compile a small list of well-known software products whose developers started a full (or large) rewrite while they held a prominent market position -- both those who lost such position during the rewrite and those who kept it.

Ideally, each item in the list would be accompanied by a reference to a reputable source telling the story.

Examples - Lost dominant position concurrently with a rewrite

- Lotus 1-2-3 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3#Decline
- Netscape Navigator - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator#The_fall_of_Netscape - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Examples - Went through rewrite while keeping dominant position

- Microsoft Windows - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_windows#Windows_NT_family
- PHP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encourage you to read Joel Spolsky's [Things You Should Never Do, Part I](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) where he addresses I believe the same point you're dealing with.

Comment: That's where I took the Lotus & Netscape examples from (see my link). I need more DOCUMENTED examples.

Comment: What do you mean by documented in all caps? I definitely believe Joel Spolsky offers enough authority on the subject, either way I assume you meant more _verbosely_, _extensively_ documented, in which case you might focus your search into more Open Source kind of projects as I doubt commercial products will share the level of detail you're looking for with the general public.

Comment: Just any statement that a prominent market position was held and a rewrite was started from any reputable source (and Joel is certainly a reputable source) will do. Joel doesn't make statements on market position in his article.

Comment: You probably also have checked here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_(programming)#See_also, where you have BIND, AOL Instant Messenger, Sun Secure Global Desktop, et al.

Comment: Internet Explorer 4 and Microsoft Word 2000 rewrote their respective layout engines.

Comment: Yes, I also checked those. Thanks Nano.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I'll add those to my list.